# Herkunft und Verbreitung von "Ausheben"

Tags: etymology

Was ist die Herkunft des Wortes "[Ausheben](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servieren#Ausheben)" in der Bedeutung von "Tisch abräumen"? Gibt es Regionen, in denen der Begriff üblicherweise umgangssprachlich verwendet wird? Wird das Wort in der Gastronomie regelmäßig verwendet oder ist es auch dort eher unüblich?

Comment: Hast Du irgendeine Quelle, die behauptet, dass *ausheben* dies bedeute, oder *ausheben* auf diese Weise nutzt? Ich konnte auf die Schnelle nichts finden.

Comment: Z.B. hier: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servieren#Ausheben

Comment: Mir ist diese Bedeutung des Wortes »Ausheben« völlig unbekannt. (Bin knapp 50 Jahre alt und lebe in Ost-Österreich)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Das hat vermutlich wenig mit der Region zu tun. Sieht eher nach einem Fachbegriff aus: https://www.google.de/search?q="ausheben"+gläser+servieren findet jede Menge Gastronomie-Seiten.

Comment: @Matthias: Genau. Geschirr wird in der Gastronomie-Fachsprache vor der Verwendung *eingesetzt* und nach der Verwendung *ausgehoben*. Ich weiß nicht woher die Begriffe stammen.

Comment: Ich habe den Begriff in dieser Bedeutung noch nie gehört, weder umgangs- noch schriftsprachlich (Deutschland, Hessen). Es scheint ausschließlich Fachsprache zu sein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ich habe nie in der Gastronomie gearbeitet, aber die breit gestreuten Google-Treffer inkl. einiger recht "offiziell" aussehender Lehrbücher und Glossare scheinen mir auf einen gängigen Fachbegriff hinzudeuten. Außerhalb dieser Domäne ist mir das Verb in dieser Bedeutung aber noch nirgendwo untergekommen (aber ich bin auch noch nicht überall gewesen). Insofern habe ich durch diese Frage etwas hinzugelernt.

Ich möchte meine eigene Theorie dazu vorstellen; leider habe ich nirgendwo einen Beleg dafür finden können.

Viele kennen die Redewendung "die Tafel aufheben" für "das Essen beenden". Sie stammt aus einer Zeit, als es in feineren Kreisen üblich war, die Tischplatten samt dem Essen in den Saal zu tragen und hernach auf gleiche Weise wieder zu entfernen. Tafel, *leeres Geschirr* und Essensreste wurden also zusammen aufgehoben = hochgehoben und dann aus dem Raum gebracht. Meine Hypothese ist nun, dass sich dieser alte Brauch in dem Fachbegriff "ausheben" erhalten hat, aber eben nun nur noch auf das Geschirr angewendet wird.

Als Indiz möchte ich zweimal die Grimms anführen.

1. **[aufheben](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?lemma=aufheben)**: "teller aufheben, wir sagen heute abnehmen, wechseln, bei
   der mahlzeit"
2. **[ausheben](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?lemma=ausheben)**: 4) ausheben für aufheben, emporheben