# Etymologie des Wortes “aufheben”

Tags: etymology

explaining the expression

> aufgeschoben ist nicht aufgehoben

(meaning something like 'rescheduled does not mean cancelled') to a friend of mine, I was wondering about the word `aufheben`, which means both `pick up` and `cancel`

What is the etymology (of the `cancel` meaning) of `aufheben`? And: are the two meanings somehow related to each other?

Comment: Könnte das hiermit zusammenhängen: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tafel_aufheben?

Comment: wow, very good find :) i knew the connection "tafeln" and "essen", but this one is new to me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the german Duden you can't find an entry in the etymology. I found a similar [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17876/herkunft-und-verbreitung-von-ausheben). The answer desrcibes how `das Aufheben der Tafel` is having the same meaning like `das Beenden des Essens`. With `aufheben der Tafel` it is meant to pick up the tabletop and carry it away and with this action you cancel or finish the lunchtime. Having a carryable tabletop is comming from medieval times. So the entire dish and lunch is served in one action.

Nowadays `aufheben` in the meaning of to cancel, is often used for cancellation of a sentence. To assign a curse to someone can be translated to `jemanden mit einem Fluch belegen` so you `make him carry the weight of the curse` or you `lay the weight of the curse down on the person`. In this way it also makes sense to pick up the weight of the curse again. `Einen Fluch aufheben` is also translated to recall the curse. So first you let the person carry the weight/burden of something and pick up the weight/burden again in order to cancel the sentence. The example you stated in your question also implies that the person who has to complete a task or fulfill a agreement doesn't want to do so. Therefore the person is carrying a burden around and will be relieved from the burden after doing whatever the person is supposed to do or the other person who forced the agreement will recall it. So in this situation `aufheben` is used as a synonym for `entlasten (engl. relieve)`. So the party that was affected negativly by some changes is becoming its freedom back and is therefore `entlastet` because something or someone `picked up the weight/burden again`.

Note: `etwas aufheben` with the meaning of `to cancel` always implies it's easier for the opponent party to cancel the agreement, than it is for the other party to fulfill it. For example the king can just order to unblock a blocked road again, while you would have to put in a lot of efford to pass the road that the king blocked before. To be able to cancel/aufheben something, it always implies the opponent party has a higher rank or you are in debt.

Comment: kind of "oversize tray" :)

Comment: Correct. It was common to use the same room for an assembly and for the feast. So it was handy to have portable tables, and also you could prepare everything before serving it.

Comment: I fail to see hos such a narrow meaning could be transfered to legal terminology. The rest of the answer that does not deal with dinner plates is in sum just pointing out that a metaphor can work in multiple ways. This is surely important, but nothing definite. Each line implies new interesting questions. Especiall the explanation aluding to a vertical hierarchy is interesting (cp. *aufgeben*, but *to submit*, both declaring defeat or sending a package, also *surrender*). Only one, the road block one, reinforces the primary idea. I do not count *mit einem Fluch belegen*, because ...

Comment: ... *Auslegung von Gesetzen* (interpretation, statutory law) has little to do with laying, and looks to be very close to Latin *lego*, English *law* (while *bekannt machen, öffentlich aushängen* might be an influence). Anyhow, it is possible that the sense *to end* was already there, when lords more busy with feasting than lawing properly re-etymologized the word. Without historical evidwnce, I have no reason to believe that *aufheben* meant *to remove heavy things* in general, rather than in this narrow sense, *end*.

Answer (score 8):

Consider the English phrase:

> The ban was lifted.

Which is equivalent to:

> Die Sperre wurde aufgehoben.

In this case, both words (*lifted*, *aufgehoben*) are used in the meaning of *cancelled* (or more literally: *taken away*, *removed*), although they usually have different, but also pretty equivalent meanings.

Comment: Compare *shop-lifting* to Gothic *hliftuz* "thieve" which is akin to Gr *klepto-* according to wiktionary.

Comment: Also *ein Geheimnis lüften*

Answer (score 4):

[Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GA06400#XGA06400) provides under section 9 of *aufheben* the folllowing:

> noch häufiger ist die abstraction des aufhebens, wegnehmens, tilgens und abschaffens

There are numerous examples for the meaning *cancellation*, like *Vorschrift, Ausnahmezustand, Hausarrest* and it is interesting, that the opposite, the establishment can frequently be formulated with *erlassen*, which may mean *put down* in the similar way as *aufheben* means *lift*.

Comment: You mean "the establishing", "the creation" which stands in contrast to the other meaning "to dismiss, to dispose of". Note that while "to put down" accurately reflects the contrast, it does not paraphrase the semantics of a bare preposition less *Lassen Sie das*! I am not sure whether I am complaining about the choice of words or the difficulty of paraphrasing in a second language. *pick* <> *put* is a good comparison, in the sense that we are looking at basically two different words.

Answer (score 2):

Since we're happily speculating away here, note that Latin already has the same ambiguity: *tollere* means both *to take away (metaphorically), to abolish* and *to take away (literally), to lift*.

The shift in meaning is fairly natural: If I want to take something away, first I need to lift it, or at least pick it up. But it might also well be the case that *aufheben* is a semantic loan from Latin.

Comment: It's not exactly "the same ambiguity". In *to pick up* there's a sense "to start to use", and in *aufheben* there's a sense "to save for later" (alternatively *behalten*), both implying "to reject not". I am not sure whether the opening question was aware of that. It is approximately the opposite of *to discard (a law)*. Also, *aufheben* does not generally have the denotional sense "to take an object away from someone", though it's implied in a restricted sense, e.g "eine Erlaubnis aufheben". That's hardly natural. We might well be looking at an old idiom, indeed, but ...

Comment: .. I do not consider legalese a natural language, although, the archaic structures are sometimes more naturally grown than laid out synthetically in a perfect system. It is especially prone to corruption. I would try to look further than Latin. Just compare *lesen* "sammeln; to read, teach", La *legare* "lesen", *illegal*, *lösen*, *erlösen*, *ablösen*, ***eine Versammlung auflösen***. Cp Dutch *taal*, En *tell*, Ger *Zahl*, *zählen*, *erzählen*, *erteilen*, *ernennen*, *einstellen*, *annehmen*, *wegnehmen*, *abziehen*, *zerren*, En *tear*, Fr *tirer*, En *tire, **retire**, try, trial* ...

Answer (score 1):

When looking at the etymology of [heben](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GH04581#XGH04581) we can see that it was and is not only used in the meaning of *to lift, to heave* (same root) but also figuratively, e.g. (incomplete list!):

- In finance we used it in the meaning of to lift money up from a storage which today turned into *Geld abheben*.
- in mathematics it is used as *heben* in the meaning of to level up (i.e. to cancel), and also with prefix *auf-* as *aufheben* in the meaning of to resolve.
- last but not least if we say ***aufheben*** in the meaning of *to cancel* it is the figurative use of *to heave away*.
  So if we say *eine Tafel aufheben* we not only say we heave away the cutlery but the people of the dinner party also move away to another place, after they had lifted themselves up of the chairs (*sich erheben*).

Comment: Hmmm... instead of *heave* I would rather use *lift*.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: *heave* is because of the shared etymological roots (we were not asked for the meaning but for the etymology but I do like you answer which show a similar figurative approach with totally different words)

Comment: but *to heave* has a connotation of heavy lifting ("lift or haul -- something heavy -- with great effort"), which I would not associate with, say, taking away cutlery.